# In pandas, can I avoid a loop when assigning value based on specific row values?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, for-loop, list-comprehension

I have three columns,['date'] which has the date, ['id'] which holds product id's and ['rating'] which holds product ratings for each product for each data, I want to create a dummy variable ['threshold'] which equals 1 when within the same value of ['id'] the value of rating went from anywhere above 5 to anywhere below 6.
My code would use a for loop as follows:

```
df['threshold']=np.zeros(df.shape[0])
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
        if df.iloc[i]['id'] == df.iloc[i-1]['id'] and df.iloc[i-1]['rating']>5 and df.iloc[i]['rating']<6:
            df.iloc[i]['threshold']=1
```

Is there a way to perform this without using a for loop?

Comment: Please include a small sample of your data along with your desired results. Take a look at [how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) and compare with [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) for equal and convert output mask to integers `0,1` by [`Series.view`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.view.html):

```
df['threshold']= (df['id'].eq(df['id'].shift()) & 
                  df['rating'].shift().gt(5) & 
                  df['rating'].lt(6)).view('i1')
```